# How can I best implement this React Transition?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am attempting to create an easy-to-use UI/UX selection system.

Essentially, on the viewport, I first have 3 "difficulty" components that choose what "difficulty level" you want.

Once clicked, they should then transition to the next selection phase, which would be "male" or "female".

Clicking this button should move/remove the difficulty level component to the left (out of the viewport), and move the sex selection into the viewport.

How would I implement this?

I also plan on implementing a "Go back" feature as well in the future, so that users can go back and forth from Difficulty and Sex components.

## My ideas

1. Once the button is clicked, I just use CSS to transition the difficulty component out of the viewport, and the "sex" component into the viewport. After the transition, I give that component a `display: none` to remove it completely from the user.

Concerns: This doesn't seem efficient. Should I be removing the component entirely? If so, where does one begin to do that?

2. Another method would be to remove/add the components as needed...which I believe would require using the `ComponentDidMount()` and `ComponentDidUnmount()` functions, and then using the React Transition Group library to somehow transition them out?

Here is an excellent, Picasso-like, hand-drawn example from myself:

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is how to do the transition.
Typically, setting `display: none` stops any sort of animation, which you don't want to do.

```
export default class Modal extends React.Component {
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    return (
      nextProps.show !== this.props.show ||
      nextProps.children !== this.props.children
    );
  }

  render() {
    const { show, children } = this.props;
    return (
      <div
        style={{
          transform: show ? 'translateY(0)' : 'translateY(-100vh)',
          opacity: show ? 1 : 0,
        }}
      >
        {children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Note that returning false from `shouldComponentUpdate` will stop re-rendering the modal and its children.
The `children` could be anything or nothing. So when you don't want to show it, render an empty `div` outside view window is very efficient.

**Key takeaway**

- `display: none` shouldn't need most of the time. It doesn't support animation, and render function can return `<div />` or `null`.
- React components will re-render when received new props or updated state, regardless display type and window position.
- Mare sure have a clear understanding on [rendering lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html), not all mounting/updating functions can `setState`, and you can stop re-rendering manually.

Comment: Thank you for your help. After trying to read your code, I think I am jumping ahead too far. I think I'll have to do a few React tutorials to understand this better.

Comment: @wonkaswilly edited a little bit. Once you try the code above, and think it solves your problem. Please make it as an answer. Thanks.

Comment: To be honest, I will have to go back and understand properly how `shouldComponentUpdate` works. I didn't even know it could take arguments, and how that works. I'm sure your answer is correct; I will mark it down for now, and go study the lifecycle of React Components more thoroughly.

Comment: @wonkaswilly https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html It's better to read the doc first. To really understand how these work, my recommendation is to use real API call. Firebase is a good resource to get your API call going.

Comment: I appreciate your tips; I will definitely check it out. Thanks again!